# Cannot create docker images

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I try to create a Docker image in the developerWorks organization for an article. Instead of proceeding, or asking me for a container namespace, I get this error:

> BXNUI0517E: The attempt to retrieve the container namespace of the org failed because of an internal error with incident ID 238-1457636351.976-5559997. Try again later. If this problem continues, go to Support. For other help options, see the Bluemix Docs.

It has been doing it consistently for three days now. How do I use Docker on Bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should engage the IBM Containers team to investigate your space. I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the 
     upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support 
     widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of 
     assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check namespace by running the command - "cf ic namespace get"

Also container creation in US/UK regions was not working from March 8. Refer to
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

RESOLVED: Possible issues with creating IBM Containers on US South and United Kingdom regions
Some users are currently experiencing issues when creating IBM Containers from the Bluemix UI in both US South and United Kingdom regions.
The UI will return a "catalog:createContainer_errorWithIncidentId" error.

The operations team is aware of the issue and is currently working to resolve it.
The IBM Containers CLI is unaffected and can be used as workaround.

Update March 9th 3:30 PM UTC (9:30AM EST): the issue has been addressed and successfully resolved.

Updated:    Mar 9, 2016 9:05 PM UTC+0530
Starts: Mar 8, 2016 4:30 AM UTC+0530
Category:   IBM Containers
Region(s):  eu-gb
us-south

Answer (score 0):

if this is the first time that you are using container before creating a container you need to create a namespace in a specific space. I suggest you to create the first container using UI\dashboard and then use that space in Command line plugin (cf ic).

login to bluemix:

```
- cf api https://api.[REGION].bluemix.net
- cf login  -u your_email -o your_org -s yourspace_where_you_created_first_container
- cf ic login
```

you can retrieve the namespace for the space issue: cf ic namespace get